# Why isn't class function being called through Ajax in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

**This is the .js function:-**

```
function SaveMergeOrderSetting(obj) {
    debugger;
    try {
        if (obj != null) {
            //Block multiple events
            $(obj).addClass('disable-click');
        }
        var isOrderMergeConfigured = $("#ddlMergeOrderSettings").val();
        var IsOrderMerge = false;
        if (isOrderMergeConfigured == "True") {
            IsOrderMerge = true;
        }
        else {
            IsOrderMerge = false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '/Store/CallOrderSettings/',
            data: { IsOrderMergeConfigured1: IsOrderMerge },
            success: function (data) {
                obj = data;
                if (obj == "True") {
                    closeConfirmPopup();
                }
                if (obj != null) {
                    //Block multiple events
                    $(obj).removeClass('disable-click');
                }
            }, error: function () {
                if (obj != null) {
                    //Block multiple events
                    $(obj).removeClass('disable-click');
                }
            }
        });
```

**This is the class function:-**

```
public bool CallOrderSettings(bool IsOrderMergeConfigured)
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
    }
    catch
    {}
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: You don't show us how the URL `/Store/CallOrderSettings/` is resolved into a call to that function.  You should begin debugging this by looking -- first -- to see if you get a `404 Not Found` response on the client end.   Then -- what do you see in the server logs when the server receives this URL and attempts to resolve it.

Comment: I got this error in .js file "Error in highLightRows : TypeError: Unable to get property 'enable' of undefined or null reference"